# "IllegalArgumentException" in SonarQube Community plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Recently, when I try to analyze code in **Android Studio** (`Analyze > Inspect Code`) I always obtain this error:

```
11:35:28 IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'sonarServerName' of org/intellij/sonar/persistence/SonarServers.get must not be null
```

In other projects it works fine. When `IllegalArgumentException` link is clicked, this screen is shown:

[image: IDE Fatal Error: Exception in SonarQube Community plugin]

Obviously, I don't want to disable plugin.

Exception text copied here:

```
Argument for @NotNull parameter 'sonarServerName' of org/intellij/sonar/persistence/SonarServers.get must not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'sonarServerName' of org/intellij/sonar/persistence/SonarServers.get must not be null
    at org.intellij.sonar.persistence.SonarServers.get(SonarServers.java)
    at org.intellij.sonar.analysis.DownloadIssuesTask.from(DownloadIssuesTask.java:53)
    at org.intellij.sonar.analysis.SonarQubeInspectionContext.performPreRunActivities(SonarQubeInspectionContext.java:143)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.GlobalInspectionContextBase.initializeTools(GlobalInspectionContextBase.java:340)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.GlobalInspectionContextImpl.runTools(GlobalInspectionContextImpl.java:339)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.GlobalInspectionContextBase$6.run(GlobalInspectionContextBase.java:283)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.GlobalInspectionContextBase.performInspectionsWithProgress(GlobalInspectionContextBase.java:280)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.GlobalInspectionContextBase$4.run(GlobalInspectionContextBase.java:241)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Anyone has experienced this issue? Where is the problem and what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure a SonarQube server to use as per the [README](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin/blob/master/README.md) from the plugin repository:

> After the installation, you first of all need to configure the
>   connection to your Sonar server. This is done per project and/ or
>   module. You can use a remote server or a local one on your machine.
>
> In your IDE go to Preferences -> SonarQube.
>
> [image: In your IDE go to Preferences -> SonarQube]
>
> Click Add, enter the address of your Sonar server and the credentials (if needed) and click OK.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks @NikitaBaksalyar. I configured it and created the server several days ago, but somehow <NO SONAR> server was set. I only needed to select the right server.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be thrown when you created the server in the project settings but not in the global settings. You have to select & add the server in the global settings as well.